# Setting up a filter in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Creating a filter to sort through quotes data, but having problems with creating the correct functions.

HTML:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <h3> Theme filter: </h3>
    <div>
      <button v-on:click="userFilterKey = 'movies'"> Search movies</button>
      <button v-on:click="userFilterKey= 'all'"> Search all</button>
      <button v-on:click="userFilterKey= 'games'"> Search games </button>
      <div v-for="quote in quotes" v-bind:key="quote.id">
        <p>Souce: {{ quote.source }} </p>
        <p>Quote: {{ quote.quote }} </p>
        <p>Theme: {{ quote.theme }} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: "Welcome to Vue.js!",
      quotes: [],
      userFilterKey: "all",
    };
  },
 methods: {
    userFilter: function () {
      return this[this.userFilterKey];
    },
    all: function () {
      return this.quotes;
    },
    movies: function () {
      return this.quotes.filter((theme) => (quotes.theme = "movies"));
    },
    books: function () {
      return this.quotes.filter((theme) => (quotes.theme = "books"));
    },
    quotesIndex: function () {
      axios
        .get("linktodata")
        .then((response) => {
          this.quotes = response.data;
        });
    },
```

How do I create filters to sort through the theme key of the quotes array within my link?

Comment: could you make a codepen with example data (not axios).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [computed prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    quotes: [{
        id: 1,
        source: 'a',
        quote: '',
        theme: ''
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        source: 'b',
        quote: '',
        theme: 'movies'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        source: 'c',
        quote: '',
        theme: 'games'
      }
    ],
    userFilterKey: "all"
  }),
  computed: {
    filteredQuotes() {
      if (this.userFilterKey === 'all') {
        return this.quotes
      }
      return this.quotes.filter(v => v.theme === this.userFilterKey)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="userFilterKey = 'all'"> Search all </button>
  <button @click="userFilterKey = 'movies'"> Search movies</button>
  <button @click="userFilterKey = 'games'"> Search games </button>

  <div v-for="quote in filteredQuotes" :key="quote.id">
    <p>Souce: {{ quote.source }} </p>
    <p>Quote: {{ quote.quote }} </p>
    <p>Theme: {{ quote.theme }} </p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pipes. Its something that does the filter in client side and is faster. may be that solves your problem